# Modify horizontal list view to look like a semicircle in android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am newbie with android,

I have made an horizontal list view with adapter so I show a list of imagesView horizontally in the screen  of my mobile, each image view is inside a LinearLayout.

What I want to do is to add some effects to the behavior of the horizontalListView, I want the five elements are shown in the screen behave a little different, the element in the middle be the largest then as long as the other elements are near the end of the screen decrease the width and the height.

How could I do that in android ?

Which are the methods I should change or add ?

Greetings,
Ariel

Comment: do you have a different layout for each listView? It will be great if you include a sketch...

Comment: No, each element of the list view only have a linearLayout and inside the linearLayout an imageView and a textView.